# Add a constraint to only allow updating column to a higher value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

We have a table that keeps track of delivery_numbers from each of our tills. A column holds an integer to represent the last delivery number for each till, each till represented by one row. Errors in the application, that we cannot find, sometimes update the delivery number to a number that is lower. We need to make sure that this number is only updated increasing in value and can never be updated to a lower value.

The below code is an example of what is required:

```
CREATE TABLE [till_deliveries](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [delivery_no] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_till_deliveries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 

insert into [till_deliveries] values (1,100), (2, 200)

--This update should be permitted
update [till_deliveries]
set [delivery_no] = 101
where id = 1

--This update should not be allowed by constraint
update [till_deliveries]
set [delivery_no] = 199
where id = 2
```

Ideally, we'd like to put a constraint on the column but cannot work out how to do it, or if it is even possible.
In case I did not describe well enough: this does not depend on other row values. Each till has its own delivery numbers that are independent from each other.

Comment: You need to use a trigger for this type of constraint, or alternatively define the column as `identity()`.

Comment: If triggers not possible can you add a where clause ie where 199>deliveryno. As Gordon said triggers most robust

Comment: @GordonLinoff, why not a CHECK constraint with a function?

Comment: @TabAlleman Because such a constraint would require 2 values - the prior value and the new value. There is no syntax that supports that in a constraint or a function. A function cannot access the deleted table directly - and the deleted table does not exist outside of an executing trigger. So you've just seconded the use of a trigger - the function adds nothing.

Comment: Yes. A trigger it is. Tx all.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question.